# Problema con el navegador y highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, google-chrome, firefox

Cuando hice la aplicación funcionaba de maravilla. Creo una gráfica de highCharts en base a varias consultas a la base de datos y la armo con PHP. Esto es llamado por medio de un AJAX, este es el ajax:

```
//TRAEMOS LA INFORMACIÓN CUANDO SE DA CLICK EN JUSTIFICACIONES
$(document).on('click', '#justifica', function(e) 
{

e.preventDefault();
//Borramos el elemento que tiene una gráfica.
    $('#chart_script').remove();

//limpiamos el div que se llenará con los datos
$('#response').html("");

//llamada a AJAX
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/control_administrativo/justificaciones_form.php',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data)
            {
      //cuando regresa la información la metemos en el reponse y
      //le damos formato de Datatable a la tabla
        $('#response').html(data);
        $('#tabla_justificaciones').DataTable({
            "scrollY": "250px",
            "paging": true
        });

        //De nuevo una llamada a AJAX
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'php/control_administrativo/justificacion_chart.php',
                        method:'POST',
                        success:function(chart)
                        {
            //Si responde PHP  con una X no mostrar nada.
                            if (chart=="X")
                            {
                                    $('#chart').html('');
                            }

                            else
                            {
              //Creamos el tag con javascript
                                var script=document.createElement('script');
                                script.type='text/javascript';
                                script.id='chart_script';
                                $("body").append(script);

              //le asignamos la información que se armó en PHP
                                $('#chart_script').html(chart);

              //triggereamos el chart para que se muestre
                                show_chart();
                            }
                        }
                    });
    }
});
});
```

El problema viene aquí.
AJAX me responde correctamente la información:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De hecho si copio el código que me regresa AJAX y lo abro en un nuevo documento sale la gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta gráfica tiene 4 niveles de drilldown, aprox una 11 mil líneas de código, lo cuál no es problema. El problema viene aquí.
Después de 3 segundos AJAX me da la respuesta pero me aparece un error.
Primero que el código que creé está mal elaborado y al final que no encuentra el trigger para lanzar el chart
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si doy click en el error de la VM me da la pestaña de Sources y aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como si no se hubiera formado correctamente el script, pero PHP y AJAX me estan respondiendo de forma completa.
Quiero suponer que es un error o que tenga algo que ver con el navegador, no sé.
Quizá un problema con la caché del navegador o algo esta pasando.
Lo curioso es que no pasa en todas las máquinas, aveces si aparece completo con otros usuarios y con otros no.

No tengo ni la más mínima idea que pueda suceder. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema es que despues del append y la creacion del script aun no existe el metodo que intentas invocar o al menos el handle de javascript no se entera aun

tal vez esperando un par de segundos, algo como:

```
          //le asignamos la información que se armó en PHP
                            $('#chart_script').html(chart);

          //triggereamos el chart para que se muestre
                            setTimeout(function(){ show_chart();},2000);
                        }
```